# Get the dates of 4 quarters mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want the start and end dates of 4 quarters, so that I can use `BETWEEN` function to count how much data added in each quarter. How do I get the dates?

```
$this->db->select('SUM(CASE WHEN(data.added_on BETWEEN MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) + INTERVAL QUARTER(CURDATE())-2 QUARTER AND MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) + INTERVAL QUARTER(CURDATE())-1 QUARTER - INTERVAL 1 DAY ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) data_quarter3');
```

this will work for the previous quarter, but I don't want this. Any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the dates, just specify the quarter and year you want in your WHERE statement

```
WHERE QUARTER(data.added_on) = 2 AND YEAR(data.added_on) = YEAR(NOW())
```